# Heroku H10 error message 'App Crashed'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, vagrant

All of a sudden I cannot get my Heroku app to open in the browser. I am getting the following error:

```
'2016-04-29T21:36:08.637580+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10     desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=james-cf-app.herokuapp.com request_id=4d379441-00d0-4a1f-8578-080dd996b1da fwd="209.49.226.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes'
```

After searching I have tried multiple things like restarting Heroku and `ps:scale web=1`. Here is the log after Heroku run rails console:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant$ heroku run rails console
Running rails console on james-cf-app... up, run.1820
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport- 4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `re                                                                                                quire': /app/app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:29: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expec                                                                                            ting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.                                                                                            rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.                                                                                            rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.                                                                                            rb:274:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.                                                                                            rb:360:in `require_or_load'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.                                                                                            rb:317:in `depend_on'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.                                                                                            rb:233:in `require_dependency'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:472:in `block (2                                                                                             levels) in eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `block in                                                                                             eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `eager_loa                                                                                            d!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_loa                                                                                            d!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:                                                                                            in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:                                                                                            in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `ins                                                                                            tance_exec'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run                                                                                            '
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `blo                                                                                            ck in run_initializers'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongl                                                                                            y_connected_component'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_componen                                                                                            t_from'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected                                                                                            _component'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_componen                                                                                            t'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run                                                                                            _initializers'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `init                                                                                            ialize!'
    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.                                                                                            rb:274:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.                                                                                            rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.                                                                                            rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.                                                                                            rb:274:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `requ                                                                                            ire_environment!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:                                                                                            142:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:                                                                                            67:in `console'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:                                                                                            39:in `run_command!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (re                                                                                            quired)>'
    from /app/bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from /app/bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an application crash, something is wrong with the code. Is the app working on your localhost i.e. `rails s` and `rails c`?

Answer (score 0):

You have an unexpected end-of-input error on line 29 of comments_controller.rb